# Can I install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a SAMSUNG NP300E5X-S01?

Tags: 12.04, laptop, samsung, compatibility, setup

I want to buy a laptop, but I want to use it with Ubuntu! So, Can I install it on the SAMSUNG NP300E5X-S01 ?

Thanks !

Specifications

Processor : 
Brand/Family : Intel Core i5-3210M
CPU Speed : 2.5GHz
Cache Memory : 3MB
Turbo Boost : 3.1GHz

"RAM" Memory : 
RAM Type : DDR3
Installed RAM : 4Gb
RAM FSB speed : 1600MHz
RAM Up to : 8GB

Drives : 
Hard Drive Type : HDD
Hard Drive Capacity : 500Gb
Rotational speed(RPM) : 5400RPM
Hard Drive Connection : SATA
CD/DVD Drive : DVD Super Multi DL
Memory card reader : SD, SDHC, SDXC Card Reader

Graphic Card : 
VGA Brand : NVIDIA
VGA Model : GeForce GT 610M
VGA Dedicated Memory : 1GB
VGA Memory Type : DDR3

Screen : 
Screen Type : LED backlight
Screen Resolution : 1366x768Px
Screen Size : 15.6inch
High Definition : HD

Internet : 
Bluetooth : Bluetooth v 4.0
LAN : 10/100/1000 BASE-T Ethernet
WiFi : WiFi 802.11 b/g/n

Interface : 
USB : 3xUSB 2.0
HDMI : 1xHDMI
VGA/Out : Yes
Audio Ports : Yes

Multimedia : 
Speaker : Yes
Web Camera : 1.3MP
Microphone : Yes
Touch Pad : Yes

Software : 
Operating System : FreeDOS

Battery : 
Battery tech/cells : 6-cell Lithium-Ion
charger : AC Power Adapter

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you run **Ubuntu** *12.04.3 LTS, 64-bit*. *You have a slower hard drive,  but suitable RAM and processor for this. You will need to configure graphic drivers, for optimum performance.*

---

***LATER***

With that as a benchmark, you can then see if a **LiveCD** trial of **Ubuntu** *13.10 64-bit* is any improvement. *You will also need to configure graphic drivers, for optimum performance.*